# Loading page info into array, and cycling page info as URLs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I;ve built a CMS that allows users to build static pages of images and text content solely for displaying on television screens throughout our building. I've completed this to the point of viewing the display with it's pages but only if I call it explicitly in the url. The problem is, I want to load by display which is stored in the URL.

For instance, the url now if you click on Display 3 is `http://local.CMSTest.com/showDisplay.php?display=3`

and this calls a function using 3 as the display ID that grabs all pages with that display ID. This works, but in my html where I throw a `foreach` in there, it loads both pages associated with that display into a crammed page, half and half. So I know it's working but I need to store these pages into an array for javascript as well I believe.

I'm thinking there may be a way where I can load it with the first page on default and append it to the url like `http://local.CMSTest.com/showDisplay.php?display=3&page_id = 2` and then after the time is up, it can go to the next one and change the URL `http://local.CMSTest.com/showDisplay.php?display=3&page_id = 3`

So the PHP and HTML is working at this moment:

```
    <div class="row top">
        <?php include 'banner.php'?>
    </div>

    <div class="row middle" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $showDisplays['background_img']?>);">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <?if($showDisplays['panel_type_id'] == 1){?>
            <div class="fullContent" style=" height: 100%; ">
            <?php echo $showDisplays['content']?>
            </div>
            <?}?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row bottom">
        <?php include 'ticker.php';?>
    </div>

<?php }?>
```

I want to try some javascript like this that will take each page from the array, replacing the following URLs with page IDs from my previous array. How can I do this properly?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var Dash = {
nextIndex: 0,

dashboards: [
    {url: "http://www.google.com", time: 5},
    {url: "http://www.yahoo.com", time: 10},
    {url: "http://www.stackoverflow.com", time: 15}
],

display: function()
{
    var dashboard = Dash.dashboards[Dash.nextIndex];
    frames["displayArea"].location.href = dashboard.url;
    Dash.nextIndex = (Dash.nextIndex + 1) % Dash.dashboards.length;
    setTimeout(Dash.display, dashboard.time * 1000);
}
};

window.onload = Dash.display;
</script>
```

UPDATE:

Current array

```
Array ( [pageID] => 104 [page_type_id] => 1 [display_id] => 3 [slide_order] => [active] => 1 [background_img] => [panel_id] => 96 [panel_type_id] => 1 [page_id] => 104 [cont_id] => 148 [contID] => 148 [content] =>This is full content)
```

Comment: it seems like you know what you are doing with your approach. Do you have a more specific question about why your approach isn't working out? Also can you expand on "take each page from the array, replacing the following URLs with page IDs from my previous array" ?

Comment: I'm almost back to my desk and I can update maybe with the array, but basically if the URL is ?display=3 then I would want each refresh to append the page id where I can use that to load the content into the proper HTML template

Comment: @AndrewLohr I updated with my array. So basically in my javascript, I want to parse the array to put pageID onto the url like ```?display=3&pageID=104``` as the url as opposed to loading a full url in the JS

Comment: @AndrewLohr I'm experimenting right now with just doing the query and putting that into a big JSON object on the page so the refresh would just put the pageID into the URL and the html at that time would look at the attributes of that object value

Comment: @AndrewLohr would you be able to help me with a quick issue on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you would need to access your php array from javascript and you can do that by using php's `json_encode` which will convert the array to a JSON object.

Then you can use [URL search params](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) to alter the query parameters for the next URL which you can call. See the below example

```js
function setDisplay() {
  let params = new URL(document.location).searchParams;
  let pageID = params.get("pageID");
  let disply = params.get("display");
  // set the html based on pageID and display
}

function getNextURL() {
  // encode your php array to json
  // let obj = <?php echo json_encode($myArray); ?>;

  // probably what obj will look like after above line
  // this is just for this example, you should use the line commented out above
  var obj = {
    "pageID": 104,
    "page_type_id": 1,
    "display_id": 3,
  }

  let params = new URL(document.location).searchParams;
  params.set("pageID", obj.pageID);
  params.set("display", obj.display_id);

  let url = window.location.href.split('?')[0];
  let nextURL = url + "?" + params.toString();
  console.log(nextURL);
  return nextURL
}

getNextURL();
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm about to experiment with this now but I have a question first: If my array has 3 rows and I encode them to JSON to put the page ID in the url, would I then be able to just alter my html to use the JSON values for whatever the current page is?

Comment: yes after you place the pageID and display query params you will then be able to alter the HTML with the `obj` JSON (your php array)

Comment: I assume you want to change the display HTML for the current page with your php array and then after x seconds submit the next URL and repeat, right?

Comment: One thing I notice here: For each page, it's being linked from a place that calls the page with the ```?display=3```. So each display is set to be viewed with this value at all times, I just need page load to put the first pageID after the ```&``` and refresh that, and not append the display every time. RIght now I get this ```http://.../showDisplay.php?display=3?display=3&pageID=3```

Comment: okay I updated the snippet with using the plain url (no query parameters) and then appending the rest of them.

Comment: Sweet looks like that fixed it! Thanks again. So now I just need to work on refreshing and insert the nextURL, then I can just work on the HTML using the JSON object

Comment: no problem, if another question pops up feel free to ask again and send me the link to it, I'd be glad to help.

Comment: WIll do, Thanks! I'm a complete amateur when it comes to JS integrating with PHP so I'm sure I'll have a hangup somewhere haha

Comment: Sorry one more thing I noticed: The console prints the correct next URL, but does this script account for the current URL? The goal is for this, on page load, to immediately have the first pageID loaded in the URL so that I can access the attributes for it. Would i have to create a different var for current URL?

Comment: no it didn't I just updated it to create 2 functions, the new one is setDisplay(), you can use url search params to again grab the query params, just make sure you call setDisplay before you set the nextURL query params

Comment: In the future, a better way might be for you to send ajax http requests (ajax doesn't force the page to reload) to your php server to get any data you need, and then set the html when the response comes back. This way you don't have to rely on mixing your javascript with php code

Comment: Thanks I may actually do that as well!

Comment: Thank you I think I just about have it now. The only question with your latest update, is it now shows the current URL correctly but it's no longer showing nextURL in the console?

Comment: I put nextURL in a function so you will need to call getNextURL(); I'll add a call to it in the example

Comment: Ah thank you I will try that. Earlier it was loading the current URL correctly but now it's no longer doing it so I'm trying to retroactively fix that and I will test this as well

Comment: I think I figured out the other issue, does the setDisplay need to be called on page load?

Comment: it shouldn't need to be called on page load, but it would be okay if it was

Comment: @andrew_Lohr, I have a few issues on this still but I've incorporated the refresh. Still having problems with it setting the intial URL though. Would you be able to move to chat?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to

1. parse the `frames.displayArea.location.href` for its query parameters.
2. assign to `Dash.nextIndex` either `(params.page_id + 1) % Dash.dashboards.length` because the page_id is the currently diplaying page and we want the next page... or `0` if `params.page_id` is `undefined`.
3. build your URL from `dashboard.url` appending the `display_id` and `page_id` parameters.

For cleanliness, I recommend creating a var called `newURL` since we need to build a custom string.

```
display: function() {
    // step 1
    let queryString = frames.displayArea.location.href.split("?")[1];
    let paramArr = queryString.split("&");
    let params = {};

    paramArr.forEach((param) => {
        let [name, value] = param.split("=");
        params[name] = value;
    })

    console.log("params: ", params)

    // step 2
    Dash.nextIndex = (params.page_id) 
        ? (params.page_id + 1) % Dash.dashboards.length
        : 0;

    var dashboard = Dash.dashboards[Dash.nextIndex]; 

    // step 3
    let newURL = dashboard.url + "?display_id=" + params.display_id
        + "&page_id=" + Dash.nextIndex;

    // Unrelated nit: bracket access IMHO should only be used when specifying a 
    // property by the string value contained in a variable, or when the 
    // property name would be an invalid javascript variable name (starting 
    // with a number, including spaces, etc)
    frames.displayArea.location.href = newURL;

    setTimeout(Dash.display, dashboard.time * 1000);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your thoughtful answer! I'm trying this now but ti doesn't appear to do a ny refresh of the page or append the page id to the url here